# How to sort columns in Excel programmatically using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel

we are generating an Excel report and we need to sort the data programmatically before saving the file.

Is it possible to sort a specific column of an Excel file programmatically using vb.net?

As per your suggestion, in order to generate excel report with sorting on specific column I just implemented the logic as below..

```
Dim MyRange As Excel.Range
  gobjExcelReportSheet.Activate()
      MyRange = gobjExcelReportSheet.Range("A8", "L8")
      MyRange.Select()
      MyRange.Sort(Key1:=MyRange.Range("L8"), _
                   Order1:=XlSortOrder.xlAscending, _
                   Header:=XlYesNoGuess.xlGuess, _
                   MatchCase:=False, _
                   Orientation:=XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns)
```

I tried this logic just before saving the file and even just after saving the file but it is not giving any result i.e. with sorting result or even I am not getting any error.

But the following code works....

gobjExcelReportSheet.Application.Selection.Autofilter()

But there is no option for sorting programmetically.

Please help me...

Thanks!

Comment: Is the report being generated by using the Office Interop Assemblies?  If you give a code example of what you are doing you are much more likely to get a valuable response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're using the interop assemblies this is how I do it:

```
Dim myWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = myWorkbook.Worksheets(aSheetName)
myWorkSheet.Activate()
Dim myRange As Excel.Range

myRange = myWorkSheet.Range("A1", "L10")
myRange.Select()


myRange.Sort(Key1:=myRange.Range("D1"), _
                        Order1:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns)
```

Basically you need to select a range (in this case A1:L10, then choose to sort it by a certain column (D).

Comment: I have implemented this, but I am getting expected result even not getting any error. Do I need to do any other settings? Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: I take it you mean  you're not getting the expected result? If so, then we need much more information. Please edit your question showing what you've done so far.

Comment: Hi All,

Now its working with following code....

MyRange.Range("A8").Sort(Key1:=MyRange.Range("L8"), Order1:=XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Header:=XlYesNoGuess.xlGuess, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns)

Along with other lines as mentioned above.

Thank you.

Comment: Good. An upvote and/or an accepted answer (hint, click on the tick) would be nice then? ;)

Comment: Thank you. It's not really about the rep it's that it helps everyone know whether or not it's the correct answer.